# Exception caught by widgets library (getx reminder application)

Tags: flutter, exception, datetimepicker, flutter-getx, intl

I am a new flutter learner and I need help to solve the error. I currently doing a application that need to set remainder for the task after the user input the details and select the time and repeat. Everyone know how to solve this error. I have check back my code and there are nothing error line the only hint that point to the error is on the line in the image that I underline (final date = DateFormat.jm().parse(task.startTime);) Appreciate those help, thank you.

Error:
[════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
Trying to read   from 6:00 AM at 5
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════]

Output of Dubug Console Image:
[enter image description here][1]

Code for showing the information:

```
_addTaskBar() {
    String time = DateFormat.yMMMMd().format(DateTime.now()).toString();
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
      children: [
        //Date Time
        Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Text(time, style: subHeadingStyle),
            Text('Today', style: headingStyle),
          ],
        ),
        MyButton(
            label: '+ Add Task',
            onTap: () {
              Get.to(() => const AddTaskPage());
            })
      ],
    );
  }

  //Date Bar
  Container _addDateBar() {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
        top: 6,
        right: 3,
        left: 20.0,
      ),
      child: DatePicker(
        DateTime.now(),
        width: 80,
        height: 100,
        selectedTextColor: Colors.white,
        deactivatedColor: Colors.grey,
        selectionColor: primaryClr,
        initialSelectedDate: DateTime.now(),
        daysCount: 60,
        onDateChange: (newDate) {
          setState(() {
            selectedDate = newDate;
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  //Tasks List
  _showTasks() {
    return Expanded(
      child: Obx(
        () => RefreshIndicator(
          onRefresh: () => _taskController.getTasks(),
          child: _taskController.taskList.isEmpty
              ? _noTaskMsg()
              : ListView.builder(
                  scrollDirection:
                      SizeConfig.orientation == Orientation.landscape
                          ? Axis.horizontal
                          : Axis.vertical,
                  itemCount: _taskController.taskList.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    final task = _taskController.taskList[index];
                    print(task.toMap());
                    if (task.repeat == 'Daily' ||
                        task.date == DateFormat.yMd().format(selectedDate) ||
                        (task.repeat == 'Weekly' &&
                            selectedDate
                                        .difference(
                                            DateFormat.yMd().parse(task.date))
                                        .inDays %
                                    7 ==
                                0) ||
                        (task.repeat == 'Monthly' &&
                            DateFormat.yMd().parse(task.date).day ==
                                selectedDate.day)) {
                      **final date = DateFormat.jm().parse(task.startTime);**
                      final myTime = DateFormat('HH:mm').format(date);
                      print(myTime);
                      NotifyHelper.showScheduleNotification(
                          task: task,
                          hour: int.parse(myTime.toString().split(':')[0]),
                          minutes: int.parse(myTime.toString().split(':')[2]));

                      return AnimationConfiguration.staggeredList(
                        position: index,
                        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1300),
                        child: SlideAnimation(
                          verticalOffset: 300,
                          child: FadeInAnimation(
                            child: GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () => _showBottomSheet(context, task),
                              child: TaskTile(task),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    } else
                      return Container(height: 0);
                  }),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Helper class:

````
  // notificationsPlugin
  //Instances
  static final flutterNotificationService = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
  String selectedNotificationPayload = '';
  static final BehaviorSubject<String> selectNotificationSubject =
      BehaviorSubject<String>();

  //Methods
  //Initialze
  static intializeTimeZone() async {
    String timeZoneName = await FlutterNativeTimezone.getLocalTimezone();
    tz.initializeTimeZones();
    tz.setLocalLocation(tz.getLocation(timeZoneName));
    _configureSelectNotificationSubject();
    await _configureLocalTimeZone();
  }

  static Future<void> intialize() async {
    await _configureLocalTimeZone();
    _configureSelectNotificationSubject();

    const AndroidInitializationSettings androidInitializationSettings =
        AndroidInitializationSettings('app_icon');
    const DarwinInitializationSettings darwinInitializationSettings =
        DarwinInitializationSettings();

    const InitializationSettings initializationSettings =
        InitializationSettings(
            android: androidInitializationSettings,
            iOS: darwinInitializationSettings);

    await flutterNotificationService.initialize(initializationSettings,
        onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: onDidReceiveNotificationResponse);
  }

  //Notification Details
  static Future<NotificationDetails> _notificationDetails() async {
    const AndroidNotificationDetails androidNotificationDetails =
        AndroidNotificationDetails('id', 'tasks',
            channelDescription: 'reminder for your tasks',
            importance: Importance.max,
            priority: Priority.max,
            playSound: true);
    const DarwinNotificationDetails darwinNotificationDetails =
        DarwinNotificationDetails();

    return const NotificationDetails(
        android: androidNotificationDetails, iOS: darwinNotificationDetails);
  }

  static void onDidReceiveNotificationResponse(
      NotificationResponse notificationResponse) async {
    final String? payload = notificationResponse.payload;
    if (notificationResponse.payload == null) {
      debugPrint('notification payload: $payload');
      return;
    }
    debugPrint('notification payload: $payload');
    selectNotificationSubject.add(payload!);

    Get.to(NotificationPage(payload: payload));
  }

  //Show Notification
  static Future<void> showNotification({
    required String title,
    required String body,
    required String? payload,
  }) async {
    var details = await _notificationDetails();

    await flutterNotificationService.show(1, title, body, details,
        payload: payload);
  }

  //Scheduling Notification
  static Future<void> showScheduleNotification(
      {required Task task, required int minutes, required int hour}) async {
    print('showScheduleNotification Method called ${task.id}');
    var details = await _notificationDetails();
    var time = tz.TZDateTime.now(tz.local);
    await flutterNotificationService.zonedSchedule(
      task.id!,
      task.title,
      task.note,
      _nextInstanceOfTenAM(
          hour, minutes, task.remind!, task.repeat!, task.date!),
      details,
      uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
          UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime,
      androidAllowWhileIdle: true,
      matchDateTimeComponents: DateTimeComponents.time,
      payload: '${task.title}|${task.note}|${task.startTime}|',
    );
    print('showScheduleNotification Method ended ${task.id}');
  }

  static tz.TZDateTime _nextInstanceOfTenAM(
      int hour, int minutes, int reminder, String repeat, String date) {
    final tz.TZDateTime now = tz.TZDateTime.now(tz.local);
    DateTime formattedDate = DateFormat.yMd().parse(date);

    final tz.TZDateTime fd = tz.TZDateTime.from(formattedDate, tz.local);
    tz.TZDateTime scheduledDate =
        tz.TZDateTime(tz.local, fd.year, fd.month, fd.day, hour, minutes);

    scheduledDate = afterRemind(reminder, scheduledDate);

    if (scheduledDate.isBefore(now)) {
      if (repeat == 'Daily') {
        scheduledDate = tz.TZDateTime(tz.local, now.year, now.month,
            (formattedDate.day) + 1, hour, minutes);
      }
      if (repeat == 'Weekly') {
        scheduledDate = tz.TZDateTime(tz.local, now.year, now.month,
            (formattedDate.day) + 7, hour, minutes);
      }
      if (repeat == 'Monthly') {
        scheduledDate = tz.TZDateTime(tz.local, now.year,
            (formattedDate.month) + 1, formattedDate.day, hour, minutes);
      }
      scheduledDate = afterRemind(reminder, scheduledDate);
    }

    print('Date : $scheduledDate');
    return scheduledDate;
  }

  static tz.TZDateTime afterRemind(int reminder, tz.TZDateTime scheduledDate) {
    switch (reminder) {
      case 10:
        scheduledDate = scheduledDate.subtract(Duration(minutes: reminder));
        break;
      case 15:
        scheduledDate = scheduledDate.subtract(Duration(minutes: reminder));
        break;
      case 20:
        scheduledDate = scheduledDate.subtract(Duration(minutes: reminder));
        break;
      default:
        scheduledDate = scheduledDate.subtract(const Duration(minutes: 5));
    }
    return scheduledDate;
  }

  static Future<void> _configureLocalTimeZone() async {
    tz.initializeTimeZones();
    final String timeZoneName = await FlutterNativeTimezone.getLocalTimezone();
    tz.setLocalLocation(tz.getLocation(timeZoneName));
  }

  static _configureSelectNotificationSubject() {
    selectNotificationSubject.stream.listen((String payload) async {
      debugPrint('My payload is ' + payload);
      await Get.to(() => NotificationPage(
            payload: payload,
          ));
    });
  }

  static cancelNotififcationWithID(int id) async {
    await flutterNotificationService.cancel(id);
  }

  static cancelAllNotififcation() async {
    await flutterNotificationService.cancelAll();
  }
}``` 


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCfAJ.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDNVr.png
````